# Process multiple file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, bigdata

I've got to process lots of txt files (16 million of rows for each file) using awk. I've got to read for example ten files:

File #1:

```
en sample_1 200
en.n sample_2 10
en sample_3 10
```

File #2:

```
en sample_1 10
en sample_3 67
```

File #3:

```
en sample_1 1
en.n sample_2 10
en sample_4 20
```

...

I would like to have an output like this:

> source title f1 f2 f3 sum(f1,f2,f3)

```
en sample_1 200 10 1 211
en.n sample_2 10 0 10 20
en sample_3 10 67 0 77
en sample_4 0 0 20 20
```

Here my first version of code:

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
#var declaration
BASEPATH=<path_to_file>
YEAR="2014"
RES_FOLDER="processed"
FINAL_RES="2014_06_01"
#results folder creation
mkdir $RES_FOLDER
#processing
awk 'NF>0{a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2]" "$3}END{for(i in a){print i a[i]}}' $BASEPATH/$YEAR/* > $RES_FOLDER/$FINAL_RES
```

And here my output:

```
en sample_1 200 10 1
en.n sample_2 10 10
en sample_3 10 67
en sample_4 20
```

I'm a little bit confused about how to put zero column where no occurrence is found and how to get the sum of all value. 
I know I've to use this:

```
{tot[$1" "$2]+=$3} END{for (key in tot) print key, tot[key]}
```

Hope someone will help. Thank you.

******** EDITED ********

I'm trying to achieve my result in a different kind of way.
I create a bash script like this, It produces a sorted file with all of my keys, it's very huge, about 62 millions of record, I slice this file into pieces and I pass each piece to my awk script.

BASH:

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
FILENAME=<result>
BASEPATH=<base_path>
mkdir processed/slice
cat $BASEPATH/dataset/* | cut -d' ' -f1,2 > $BASEPATH/processed/aggr
sort -u -k2 $BASEPATH/processed/aggr > $BASEPATH/processed/sorted
split -d -l 1000000 processed/sorted processed/slice/slice-
echo $(date "+START PROCESSING DATE: %d/%m/%y - TIME: %H:%M:%S")
for filename in processed/slice/*; do
  awk -v filename="$filename" -f algorithm.awk dataset/* >> processed/$FILENAME
done
echo $(date "+END PROCESSING DATE: %d/%m/%y - TIME: %H:%M:%S")
rm $BASEPATH/processed/aggr
rm $BASEPATH/processed/sorted
rm -rf $BASEPATH/processed/slice
```

AWK:

```
BEGIN{
while(getline < filename){
 key=$1" "$2;
 sources[key];
 for(i=1;i<11;i++){
   keys[key"-"i] = "0";
 }
}
close(filename);
}
{
if(FNR==1){
 ARGIND++;
}
key=$1" "$2;
keys[key"-"ARGIND] = $3
}END{
for (s in sources) {
 sum = 0
 printf "%s", s
 for (j=1;j<11;j++) {
   printf "%s%s", OFS, keys[s"-"j]
   sum += keys[s"-"j]
 }
print " "sum
}
}
```

With awk I preallocate my final array, and reading `dataset/*` folder I populate its content.
I've figured out that my bottleneck came from iterating on dataset folder by awk input (10 files with 16.000.000 lines each).
Everything is working on a small set of data, but with real data, RAM (30GB) congested. Does anyone have any suggestions or advices? Thank you.

Comment: are the files sorted ?

Comment: yes, they are sorted

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = $1" "$2
    keys[key]
    val[key,ARGIND] = $3
}
END {
    for (key in keys) {
        sum = 0
        printf "%s", key
        for (fileNr=1;fileNr<=ARGIND;fileNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, val[key,fileNr]+0
            sum += val[key,fileNr]
        }
        print sum
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
en sample_4 0 0 2020
en.n sample_2 10 0 1020
en sample_1 200 10 1211
en sample_3 10 67 077
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND, with other awks just add a line `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` at the start. Pipe the output to `sort` if necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to process this algorithm on a very large set of data (10 files, each one with 16.000.000 row - 500Mb). It's taking a very huge time to process, RAM is congested and SO is going to start swapping (4 GB RAM). Do you have any suggest? Should I change programming language? Thank you.

Comment: Changing programming language will not help, changing your platform to increase memory/CPU or changing your algorithm to carve up the files somehow and process them in chunks are your only alternatives. For example you could select all of the $1 values from all of your files and then run the above script once for each key value. It will take longer but use less memory so if your current performance issue is due to running out of memory that might actually be OK. Instead of one key at a time you could choose 10 or 1,000 or some other value that makes sense for your data.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vn="<source> <title>" 'function w(m,p){while(split(a[m],t)!=b+2)sub(p," 0&",a[m])}FNR<2{f=FILENAME;o=o?o" <"f">":"<"f">";q=q?q","f:f;++b}{a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2]?a[$1" "$2]" "$NF:$0;w($1" "$2," [^ ]*$");c[$1" "$2]+=$NF}END{print n,o,"sum<("q")>";for(i in a){w(i,"$");print a[i],c[i]|"sort -k2"}}' *
<source> <title> <f1> <f2> <f3> sum<(f1,f2,f3)>
en sample_1 200 10 1 211
en.n sample_2 10 0 10 20
en sample_3 10 67 0 77
en sample_4 0 0 20 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your files are quite large, you might want to use `join` -- it *might* be faster and/or use less memory. However it requires the files to be sorted and to have a single join field.

```
join -a1 -a2 -e0 -o0,1.2,2.2     <(sed $'s/ /\034/' file1 | sort) \
                                 <(sed $'s/ /\034/' file2 | sort) | 
join -a1 -a2 -e0 -o0,1.2,1.3,2.2 - \
                                 <(sed $'s/ /\034/' file3 | sort) | 
awk '{sub(/\034/," "); print $0, $3+$4+$5}'
```

Explanation provided upon request