# Processing multiple file with different number of fields using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have many files with different data separated by space and newline.
Each file contain different number of parameter and corresponding data after keyword "alter#"

File #1:

```
encal cfreq trick  
temp alter#  
10 20 30  
40 50
```

File #2:

```
encal tie trick  
alter#   
12 34 54  
73
```

File #3:

```
encal tie trick temp  
trip miles  
alter#  
12 34 54 56  
73 34  
5
```

I wante my output file to combine all data in one file as tab separated data.

```
Filename        encal cfreq trick tie temp trip miles alter  
File1            10    20    30    NA    40 NA   NA    50  
File2            12    NA    54    34    NA NA   NA    73  
File3            17    NA    76    34    56 73   34    5
```

I tried to look at code as shown here [Process multiple file using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978240/process-multiple-file-using-awk)
but my code got very verbose and I lost my way. Can someone help me here ? I am not posting my code since I dont want to give wrong start or waste people time.

Thank you for your time in advance.

PS:Format for file1, file2, file3 is correct. My software tool is outputting file exactly same format file as I have shown. I want my output file to tab separated

Comment: Next time please do include your attempted code in your question as, if nothing else, it shows you tried and aren't just looking for someone to do your job or homework for you and so you'll get more people willing to try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS = ""
    FS = "[#]"
    OFS = "\t"
}
FNR == 1 { numFiles++ }
{
    split($1,tags," ")
    split($2,vals," ")
    for (i in tags) {
        tag = tags[i]
        val = vals[i]
        f[numFiles,tag] = val
        allTags[tag]
    }
}
END {
    printf "File"
    for (tag in allTags) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, tag
    }
    print ""

    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=numFiles; fileNr++) {
        printf "%s", ARGV[fileNr]
        for (tag in allTags) {
            val = ( (fileNr,tag) in f ? f[fileNr,tag] : "NA" )
            printf "%s%s", OFS, val
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
File    trick   temp    miles   alter   tie     cfreq   encal   trip
file1   30      40      NA      50      NA      20      10      NA
file2   54      NA      NA      73      34      NA      12      NA
file3   54      56      34      5       34      NA      12      73
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ed. Its working like a charm. Simply impressive!!